# C++ multi array - Windows has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, visual-c++, multidimensional-array

I have a window opengl appcilation, where I use a multi array, and when I try to close it, it gives the: 
"Windows has triggered a brakepoint in app.exe. 
This may be due to corruption of the heap..."

I have a header like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        static const int DATA_SIZE = 8;
        double terrain[DATA_SIZE][DATA_SIZE]
    ...
}
```

In my app I give a value to each "edgepoint" like this:

```
terrain[0][0] = 5;
terrain[0][DATA_SIZE] = 5;
terrain[DATA_SIZE][DATA_SIZE] = 5;
terrain[DATA_SIZE][0] = 5;
```

If I comment out the last line (terrain[DATA_SIZE][0] = 5;), then there is no warning message, so the problem is with that line, but I don't know what, it should work. I hope someone can help me. I use Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Comment: If you want each edgepoint (instead of each corner point) you need to fill more elements of your array (all [0][0..DATA_SIZE-1], all [DATA_SIZE-1][0..DATA_SIZE-1], etc.)

Comment: I fill the others later, I just didn't included that part, because it's too long, but thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overflowing the last element access index: use

```
terrain[0][DATA_SIZE-1] = 5;
terrain[DATA_SIZE-1][DATA_SIZE-1] = 5;
terrain[DATA_SIZE-1][0] = 5;
```

Comment: Oh my god, what a mistake, I have forgot that in the header I declare the size. Thank you!